# LIGA LED - ARDUINO

Tags: c++, arduino

Olá, sou aluno de engenharia elétrica e preciso criar um código que atualize os valores de referencia para acender 3 leds distintos em todas as possíveis combinações, a linguagem de programação é para arduino. Preciso implementar uma função que atualize os valores de um vetor de 3 posições, atualmente estou usando uma matriz para armazenar os valores de referencia para ascender os leds. Segue o código abaixo.

```
#define DELAY 1000
int LED[]={13,12,11};   
int i,j;   
int E[][3]={{LOW,LOW,LOW,},
            {LOW,LOW,HIGH},
            {LOW,HIGH,LOW},
            {LOW,HIGH,HIGH},
            {HIGH,LOW,LOW},
            {HIGH,LOW,HIGH},
            {HIGH,HIGH,LOW},
            {HIGH,HIGH,HIGH}};
void setup()
{ 
  for (int m=13; m>10; m--)
   pinMode(m, OUTPUT);
}
void loop()
{
  for(i=0; i<8; i++)
{
  for(j=0; j<3; j++)
   digitalWrite(LED[j], E[i][j]);
   delay(DELAY);
                   }
}
```

Comment: E o que deseja de nós?

Comment: Desejo que me ajudem a estruturar essa função que atualiza as posições desse vetor.

Comment: Ela já não faz o que pretende? Dica: se você listar todos os números de 0 a 7, você terá todas as sequências de 000 a 111, sem fazer manualmente.